# Concatenate groups of multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df1:

```
   a  b  c
1  0  1  4
2  0  2  5
3  1  1  3
```

and a second df2:

```
   a  b  c
1  0  1  5
2  0  2  5
3  1  1  4
```

These df's have the same goups in a and b. Within groupby of 'a' and 'b' I want df2 underneath df1:

```
   a  b  c
1  0  1  4
2  0  1  5
3  0  2  5
4  0  2  5
5  1  1  3
6  1  1  4
```

How can I combine groupby() and concat() to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `concat` then `sort_values`

```
df=pd.concat[df1,df2]).sort_values(['a','b']).reset_index(drop=True)
```